# SQL summery queries

Tags: mysql

I am having trouble getting the correct answer. My results are returning the same amount for all fields.
Please keep in mind that I am a newbie to SQL

Write a SELECT statement that returns one row for each customer that has orders with these columns:

The `email_address` column from the `Customers` table

The sum of the `item price` in the `Order_Items` table multiplied by the `quantity` in the `Order_Items` table

The sum of the `discount amount` column in the `Order_Items` table multiplied by the `quantity` in the `Order_Items` table

Sort the result set in descending sequence by the item price total for each customer.

This is my code

```
SELECT email_address,
SUM(item_price * quantity) AS item_price_total
SUM(discount_amount * quantity) AS discount_amount_total
FROM customers c JOIN order_items oi
GROUP BY email_address
Order BY item_price_total
```

Answer (score 0):

You need a join condition to relate the two tables. Otherwise, you just get a full cross-product.

```
SELECT email_address,
SUM(item_price * quantity) AS item_price_total
SUM(discount_amount * quantity) AS discount_amount_total
FROM customers c JOIN order_items oi ON c.id = oi.customer_id
                                    #^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
GROUP BY email_address
Order BY item_price_total
```

I'm just guessing the names of the columns that relate the two tables, you should replace them with the actual columns.

Comment: Thank you for your response. But now I am getting a Error Code: 1054. Unknown column 'c.id' in 'on clause'

Comment: What if there are no relations. Columns for customer table: customer_id,email_address, password, first_name, last_name, shipping_address_id, billing_address_id. Order_items table:email_address, password, first_name, last_name, shipping_address_id, billing_address_id

Comment: If you want to show the sum for each customer, there has to be a relation. How do you bill customers if you don't know which orders are for them?

Comment: Thank you I will work on this later. I have to go to work now